# How to deal with Hibernate create-drop mode with multiple apps connected to the same database?

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss7.x

We have our development environments set up so that Hibernate will create a new empty database every time our app starts:

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

This works for a single app deployed on a server but in our development environments, we typically deploy multiple applications that connect to the same database. They both use the same datasource from the app server.

The problem is that when they start in JBoss AS7, they deploy in parallel so both app servers are trying to create the tables at the same time. We get stuff like this (with anonymized table and column names):

```
16:07:25,307 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-13) Unsuccessful: create table PUBLIC.SOME_TABLE (SOME_COLUMN varchar(32) not null, SOME_OTHER_COLUMN char not null, primary key (SOME_COLUMN))
16:07:25,346 ERROR [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] (MSC service thread 1-13) Table "SOME_TABLE" already exists; SQL statement:
create table PUBLIC.SOME_TABLE (SOME_COLUMN varchar(32) not null, SOME_OTHER_COLUMN char not null, primary key (SOME_COLUMN)) [42101-161]
```

These errors get ignored and the server eventually starts but we'd like to know if there's some way to avoid this problem. We've talked about creating an app that deploys just to do the create-drop and force the other apps to wait but we're not sure how difficult it would be to change JBoss's deployment scanner to deploy apps in series instead of parallel. We're open to other ideas as well.

Answer (score 0):

In a development environment, each deployed app should have its own database schema. Not only will this solve the problem, but it will also solve the following ones:

- two developers are executing some tests, and one of them fails because the other one has modified data used by the first one
- one developer is developing an evolution that requires the schema to be changed, while the other fixes a bug on the current schema

And I'm sure there are a whole lot of other scenarii that will cause problems. Have each developer have its own schema, and everything will be much easier.

Comment: We do have our own schemas. In this case, I'm using a local h2 instance. We have multiple apps that need to touch the same database - different apps for different purposes but working with the same data. This is a common situation for web app developers.

Comment: And why don't you simply either create the schema before deploying the apps, using a SQL script, or only configure one of the deployed apps to create the schema at deployment time?

Comment: I guess that's what my question is: is it possible to configure one of the apps to create the schema? The setting for `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` is set in JBoss's configuration file, I haven't been able to find a way to set it on a per-app basis. Also, if we do this, we'd need some way to tell JBoss to deploy the app that will create the schema first and then the other apps. If there's no schema available when the other apps start (because another app is creating it), then the app will fail to start.

Comment: Typically, each app has its own database, and thus has its own hibernate configuration. In your case, you have a single database, but each app still should have its own hibernate configuration. A Hibernate app doesn't fail to start if the database tables are not there.

Comment: It does fail if schema validation is on - which we use. I guess we could just turn it on for the server that create/drops the database.